# PHP Session for input value with Submit form

Tags: php

I have 2 Pages, where an user must enter his Email Address on the first Page and on the Second page his Password, but i want display also the entered Email address above the Password.

I have tried it with `PHP Session`

Email Page:

```
<form action="save.php" method="post">
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail-Adresse">
<button class="button actionContinue" type="submit" id="btnLogin" name="btnLogin" value="Login" pa-marked="1">Einloggen</button></form>
```

save.php:

```
    <?php
   header("Location: /password");

    session_start(); 
    $name = $_POST['email'];

    if(!isset($name) OR empty($name)) {
       $name = "Gast";
    }

    $_SESSION['email'] = $name;

    echo "Hallo $name ";

    ?>
```

Password Page (Page 2):

```
<p> Geben Sie ihr Passwort ein:</p>



<?php
session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
   die("Login first");   
}

$name = $_SESSION['email'];

echo "Your email is: $name";
?>
```

Why the entered email address dont shows on the password Page? Whats wrong?

Comment: `session_start()` should be called before any display (raw text, HTML, ...)

Comment: In the header or after the header?

Comment: Check my answer. You probably want to redirect after your php code, but **before** your `echo ...` because `header()` must also be called before any output.

Comment: the `header()` line is incorrect. Once you loaded the `save.php`, it will redirect to `/password`. Also, always remember to put an `exit();` after the location redirect line, or the codes will be partially executed (depends on redirection speed).

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` must be called before any display (raw text, HTML, ...), your password file should begin as:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<p> Geben Sie ihr Passwort ein:</p>
...
```

Also, you are calling [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) at the begining of your **save.php** file. The lines after the function won't be executed, meaning that `$_SESSION['email']` won't be defined.
*Note that `header()` needs to be called before any output too !*

---

Reading the [`session_start()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

> **Note:**
>   To use cookie-based sessions, **session_start()** must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score -1):

Because you used `$name` for two places. You should change `$name = $_POST['email'];` to `$email = $_POST['email'];`

Because below code is override your `$name`

```
if(!isset($name) OR empty($name)) {
       $name = "Gast"; //if the name is not empty Gast will store inside $name
    }
```

Use the below code.

**save.php page**

```
 <?php


    session_start(); 
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    if(!isset($name) OR empty($name)) {
       $name = "Gast";
    }

    if($email != NULL){
      $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
       echo "Hallo $name ";
      header("Location: /password");
    }

    ?>
```

**Password page**

```
<?php
session_start(); 

if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
   die("Login first");   
}

echo "Your email is: $_SESSION['email']";
?>
 <p> Geben Sie ihr Passwort ein:</p>
```

Comment: `$name` is overwritten only if empty.

Comment: hm dont work for me.. Need i an input field to display the entered email address on the Passwort Page?

Comment: @annamarson how about  <p> Geben Sie ihr Passwort ein:</p> is below?

Comment: You move  header("Location: /password"); to below, after echo "Hallo $name ";

Comment: Same, nothing display..Shit